# struts2 jquery tag autocompleter key value from JSON

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, struts2

I'm trying to create autocomplete box using struts tag:

```
<sj:autocompleter name="place.id" href="/find-place-by-name" list="result" listValue="label" listKey="value" />
```

JSON get from href has construction:

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "value": "1",
        "label": "One"
    },
    {
        "value": "2",
        "label": "Two"
    },
    {
        "value": "3",
        "label": "Three"
    }
  ]
}
```

so it works well. But the problem is when I'm trying to reload page. The object 'place' has id and title, and by default after the page refreshes I can see its id in autocompleter box. That's because of used place.getId() getter from name attribute of action tag. But is there an attribute which can make me to display title and use the id? I tried already:

```
<sj:autocompleter keyValue="%{place.id}" value="%{place.title}"... />
```

but still no effect.